# Solution for a project/model

Tags: powerbi

I need to build a project on power Bi, the data model needs to be like this image, multi databases, all datas has the same data model, each user can't acess others data, i'd like some options if possible.
Another thing is, how could i identify each database.
What i tried: i set a parameter, using a list of DSN(Data Source Name), but don't know how to use it, once i don't know how to identify each database.

Scheme:
[image]

List of DSN(Parameter):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended pattern for reporting in a multi-tenant application is to deploy a separate copy of your Power BI Dataset for each company, typically in a separate workspace for each company.

The Dataset would have [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-parameters) for the Server/Database or DSN.

The alternative is to put multiple customers in each Dataset and then use [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls).  But this is more complex, and more prone to performance issues.  There's simply go good reason to put all the data into a single Dataset if the users always need to see a single company's data.

The benefits of separate Datasets are many, including simpler security administration, per-customer refresh and scale, per-customer versioning and customization, and the brand-new [cross-tenant Dataset sharing](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-september-2022-feature-summary/#post-20773-_Toc113543491) to allow your customers to access the Dataset in their home Power BI Tenant.